# AWS Cognito and Amazon API Gateway integration within Telerik NativeScript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, nativescript, cryptojs

I am developing a Telerik NativeScript application with Amazon Web Services (AWS)
and I am stuck on how to implement the logging method using Amazon Cognito.

I have two questions :

First - I have installed 'nativescript-aws' (an 'npm' library which integrates the 'aws-sdk' [AWS JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/releases) for JavaScript) and it seems working on the application, but the problem comes with AWS Cognito, I have integrated AWS Cognito through 'amazon-cognito-identity-js' [Amazon Cognito Identity SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js) but when I run the application through 'tns debug android' it stucks on "Failed to find module: "crypto", relative to: app/tns_modules/"... I have made a research and it seems that NativeScript does not support Crypto JS yet.

Second - If in any chance I succeeded to run the application I want to generate an SDK through Amazon API Gateway and integrate it within my project, thoses are the files that I need to use into the project :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/axios/dist/axios.standalone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/CryptoJS/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/CryptoJS/rollups/sha256.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/CryptoJS/components/hmac.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/CryptoJS/components/enc-base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/url-template/url-template.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/apiGatewayCore/sigV4Client.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/apiGatewayCore/apiGatewayClient.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/apiGatewayCore/simpleHttpClient.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/apiGatewayCore/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="apigClient.js"></script>
```

In summary, I want to know the best way to integrate all those libraries into my project and make it work.

Comment: Have you looked at http://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-aws which uses the same AWS JavaScript SDKs but shims the missing node.js modules to run on NativeScript.

Comment: Hello thank you for replying.
Yes I tried the plugin 'nativescript-aws' but it comes to the same issue!
Even this solution comes to the same issue!
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nodeify
The demo application is not working.
Thank you.

Comment: In that case you should consider using the mobile SDKs and calling their API directly from JavaScript - https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/. Consider making it into a nativescript plugin to help others. I am sure there would be a handful of people who'd be more than glad to contribute and drive the plugin forward.

Comment: Thank you
I fixed the issue but I couldn't even start the project.
Now I have a problem 'ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined' 
I installed Buffer from Node Package Manager 'npm install buffer' but still the same issue.

Comment: Using the mobile SDKs is one sure way to stop facing the same problems over and over again.

Comment: Thank you
I may develop the application using the AWS iOS SDK for iOS and AWS Android SDK for Android but I wanted to develop and try them using Telerik NativeScript only this is the true meaning of cross-platforming.

Comment: You will still be doing NativeScript, however NativeScript cannot implement all of node.js's API for various reasons, one of them being that NativeScript runs on mobile, not a server. And then, if you were to make the nativescript plugin using both mobile sdks you would also discover the true meaning of cross-platforming - writing one code base, that executes in a different way on the two devices, to achieve a common thing.

Comment: Yes you are right!
But the problem that the 'nativescript-nodeify' seems to be a great solution for using Node JS on NativeScript but I couldn't make it working for three days so I really wanted to make it working.
And other thing I am developing an iOS application but I don't have a Mac :/, so NativeScript is the only solution to make a fully working iOS application.

Answer (score -2):

Check out [nativescript-nodeify](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nodeify) for instructions. The cognito-specific stuff is at the very bottom. The nativescript-aws-sdk has now been deprecated so that's not a good option anymore